# AFNetworking timeout is not working

Tags: ios, timeout, afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking V2.5.4.

The default timeout for AFN is 60s, this is too long for my app. I want to set it as 20s. 
So I tried follow code `manager.requestSerializer.timeoutInterval = 20;`
But it's not working.  I searched some post saying I need add `[manager.requestSerializer willChangeValueForKey:@"timeoutInterval"];
    manager.requestSerializer.timeoutInterval = 3;
    [manager.requestSerializer didChangeValueForKey:@"timeoutInterval"];`

Still, it's not working.

Follow is my code piece

```
+ (AFHTTPRequestOperation *)sendRequestWithRequest:(NSMutableURLRequest*) request
                                       manager:(AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *)manager
                                       success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success
                                       failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure{
[manager.requestSerializer willChangeValueForKey:@"timeoutInterval"];
manager.requestSerializer.timeoutInterval = 3;
[manager.requestSerializer didChangeValueForKey:@"timeoutInterval"];
NSLog(@"manager %@, start time %lf",manager, [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]);
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [manager HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                                     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation,  id responseObject) {
                                                                         if (operation.response.statusCode) {
                                                                             success(operation, responseObject);
                                                                         }else{
                                                                             failure(operation, nil);
                                                                         }
                                                                     }
                                                                     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation,  NSError *error) {
                                                                            failure(operation, error);
                                                                     }];

[manager.operationQueue addOperation:operation];
return operation;}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? It seems I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: Try setTimeoutInterval:  on NSMutableURLRequest  instead of AFHTTPRequestSerializer